# Bcause of Null Value data is not refleting

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have two tables  view_shipment_order_release and  order_release_remark. When there is no record in order_release_remark for a given order_release_gid, there is no data shown.  I want to show data in view_shipment_order_release even if there is no data in order_release_remark. How can I do this? My query is shown below.

```
select distinct 
  vsor.shipment_gid,
  vsor.order_release_gid,
  orem1.remark_text as Related_Party,
  orem2.remark_text as ULTIMATE_CONSIGNEE_TYPE,
  orem3.remark_text as CONSIGNEE_TYPE
from 
  order_release_remark orem1,
  order_release_remark orem2,
  order_release_remark orem3,
  view_shipment_order_release vsor
--order_release_gid in('GECORP.18460727','GECORP.18435030','GECORP.18439869')
where 
  orem1.REMARK_QUAL_GID ='GECORP.CONSIGNEE TYPE'
  and orem1.order_release_gid=vsor.order_release_gid
  and orem2.REMARK_QUAL_GID ='GECORP.RELATED PARTY' 
  and orem2.order_release_gid=vsor.order_release_gid
  and orem3.REMARK_QUAL_GID ='GECORP.ULTIMATE CONSIGNEE TYPE'
  and orem3.order_release_gid=vsor.order_release_gid
  and vsor.shipment_gid='GECORP.101027274'
```

;

Comment: There is no question being asked.

Comment: I edited the question and I can relate to this question since I have more than 20yrs experience on shipping data. :D

Comment: hey, which company are you working? I work for OOCL based in Hong kong. www.oocl.com

Comment: Wow... It works but there is a slight problem if I put a value in a column and than delete it it shows as null in output.. Anyway to remove it also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use left join instead. left join will not be strict and will still display even if there is no data on related party.

```
select distinct 
  vsor.shipment_gid,
  vsor.order_release_gid,
  orem1.remark_text as Related_Party,
  orem2.remark_text as ULTIMATE_CONSIGNEE_TYPE,
  orem3.remark_text as CONSIGNEE_TYPE
from view_shipment_order_release vsor
LEFT JOIN  order_release_remark orem1
ON  orem1.REMARK_QUAL_GID ='GECORP.CONSIGNEE TYPE'
 and orem1.order_release_gid=vsor.order_release_gid
  LEFT JOIN order_release_remark orem2
  ON orem2.REMARK_QUAL_GID ='GECORP.RELATED PARTY'  
  and orem2.order_release_gid=vsor.order_release_gid
  LEFT JOIN order_release_remark orem3 
 ON orem3.REMARK_QUAL_GID ='GECORP.ULTIMATE CONSIGNEE TYPE'
and orem3.order_release_gid=vsor.order_release_gid
where vsor.shipment_gid='GECORP.101027274';
```

Answer (score 1):

I can only assume that you actually mean  order_release_remark.remark_text - which is called Related_Party in your output.

If this is indeed the case - there is nothing in this query that explains such behavior.

However, your query is bases on a view  - view_shipment_order_release (at least I hope it's a view). Views are just names for select statements  - which means that oracle is combining the query recorded in the view with the select statement you posted. My guess is, that there is something in that view that says that that  order_release_remark.remark_text  must not be empty. Or may be the records where it's empty do not have a value in order_release_gid?

Bear in mind, oracle believes that null is not equal null - so if order_release_gid is not present (is null) in two records, joining on this field will not return any rows.

Comment: Sorry I have to do select only. Also. My output. Is just related party but if related party column is null entire output is not showing. But I want that it should show all output with related party as blank.. Is there any solution